# appengine bulkdownloader to xml with nested entities

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've got an appengine app with two simple kinds of entities - `ParentEntity`s and `ChildEntity`s.  Each `ParentEntity` has a `List` of owned `ChildEntity`s.

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class ParentEntity
{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent
    private String name;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup=true)
    private List<ChildEntity> children;

...
```

With ChildEntity similarly defined.

Now, I want to download all of my data from the datastore using the technique described at http://bulkloadersample.appspot.com/ .  In their example they manage to export data to an xml file with owned entities nested inside parent entities.  But when I try to use the following configuration (which very closely resembles theirs - see http://bulkloadersample.appspot.com/showfile/bulkloader_visitactivity.yaml and look at the `activities` property), I'm met with errors.

```
- kind: ParentEntity
  connector: simplexml
  connector_options:
    xpath_to_nodes: /Parents/ParentEntity
    style: element_centric

  property_map:
    - property: __key__
      external_name: key
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string

    - property: children
      external_name: Children
      import_transform:
        transform.list_from_child_node('Children/ChildEntity')
      export_transform:
        transform.child_node_from_list('ChildEntity')


- kind: ChildEntity
  connector: simplexml
  connector_options:
    xpath_to_nodes: /Children/ChildEntity
    style: element_centric

  property_map:
    - property: __key__
      external_name: key
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string
```

I get the following error:

```
google.appengine.ext.bulkload.bulkloader_errors.ErrorOnTransform: Error on trans
form. Property: children External Name: Children. Code: transform.ch
ild_node_from_list('ChildEntity') Details: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Big update:

## I've created this sample app that you can actually view and download and test

at http://rileylark.appspot.com

You can see the output I *WANT* at http://rileylark.appspot.com/view

Download the eclipse project to see how it works.

What I want for my 500 points is a working config.yaml file that can export the data for Parent and ChildEntities into nested XML with appcfg.py download_data

Comment: why are you using transform.child_node_from_list('GradingPeriod')
 and not transform.list_from_child_node('GradingPeriod') as used in the linked example?

Comment: I'm doing it on a hunch that that's what it should be.  I haven't seen any authoritative docs anywhere, some other sites use child_node_from_list, and it seems like I want to make a child node from a list.  I've tried list_from_child_node, as well, but get a bunch of other errors.

Comment: The "list" from which to fetch the `children` seems to always be `None`.

Comment: Weird, right?  Shouldn't it be full of ChildEntities?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
transform.list_from_child_node('GradingPeriods/GradingPeriod', suppress_blank=True)
```

Comment: As the export transform?  I get `google.appengine.ext.bulkload.bulkloader_errors.ErrorOnTransform: Error on transform. Property: gradingPeriods External Name: GradingPeriods. Code: transform.list_from_child_node('GradingPeriods/GradingPeriod', True) Details: '__node__'`.

Comment: Try `transform.list_from_child_node('GradingPeriods/GradingPeriod', suppress_blank=True)`

Comment: What kind of config do you get through automatic configuration? http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Using_Automatic_Configuration

Comment: The export transform is what needs work here, I think - but I get the same errors when I use that as the import transform. I updated the original question with the config I get.  Thanks!

Comment: I updated the question again to use a brand new and simple app that you can download the source for and see exactly what's happening.